# Access user control inside asp.net Master Page from child page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms, master-pages

I'm using Asp.net with Vb and I Have user control and I put it inside My master page I need to access this UC Properties and methods from child Page.

Any help please,

Answer (score 0):

In the child page add this directive:

```
<%@ MasterType TypeName="MasterPage" %>
```

Then, the Master property of the child page will have all the type information.

Comment: I already has this directive and I added property at the master page it get and set the UC also Inside child page I can see methods and properties of UC put it gives me an error related to reference.

Comment: It gives you an error?  Perhaps the error message would be helpful and you could share it.  And, you've tested the User Control in a standard page so you know it works..right?

Comment: Here is the error message :
error BC30652: Reference required to assembly 'App_Web_transaltedbreadcrumb.ascx.cdcab7d2.padttqug, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' containing the type 'TransaltedBreadCrumb'. Add one to your project.
also yes I tested the User Control in a standard page and its working properly ..

Comment: Perhaps your user control is based on a class that is in an assembly you haven't added to your project (as a reference).